# SVN updating a common code repository OUTSIDE my repository's directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a repository of common code on svn that we use for many client CMSs. Lets call the repository CMS. Then for each client, we create a separate repository of just their files, for example CLIENT1. Every time I do an update on my local machine, I check out CMS and CLIENT1 separately.

I know that Tortoise has a command svn:Externals so that I can create a local copy of CMS in a subdirectory of CLIENT1, but we might have 20 clients, and I don't want to keep 20 copies of the same common code. Is there a way to keep a single copy of the CMS repository on my local machine outside the CLIENT1 directory, and to tell tortoise to update that repository ALSO, every time I do an update to CLIENT1, etc?

If it's relevant, I'm on a windows 7 box and SVN is on a linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **post-update-hook**(note this is a tortoisesvn feature, not supported by svn commandline!)

Just go to *"Settings->Hook Scripts"* and "Add" an new post-update hook. Fill in the appropriate command. If you do not use SVN commandline, you can use tortoiseProc.exe which gives you a [command-line interface](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)  as well:
[image]